# Type Error: Cannot read property 'push' of null while creating Cascading Dropdowns

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, cascading, sharepoint-list

I am getting the

> Type Error: Cannot read property 'push' of null

in the **SPServices js** file while implementing **Cascading Dropdowns**. I am including the js files `jquery-1.10.1.min.js` and `jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js` in the JavaScript file, that I am adding to the custom New form of the List. The code I am using is:

```
$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
    relationshipList:"Team Name",
    relationshipListParentColumn:"Team",
    relationshipListChildColumn:"Title",
    parentColumn:"Team",
    childColumn:"Member Name",
    debug: true
});
```

How to resolve this error and what is the cause of the problem?

Comment: You are instructing SPServices to push something into an Array which does not exist (or you gave SPServices a String or Object or anything but an Array). Most Likely your own code and not related to SPServices, as SPServices has been around for years. Learn to use the Browser F12 debugging tools and check where the error occurs

Comment: Thank you. I checked the issue and resolved it. One of the column names had been wrongly written.